# trying to select dynamic date from date picker

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium. I am trying to select dynamic date from the calendar. screenshots attached please help me out.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add HTML with text, rather than in screenshot. And do you know the data picker comes from any known UI plugin, so that we can access the plugin site to verify code before post the code at here.  If your app has public url  to access is better

Comment: @Ramesh So what is issue ? What you have tried ?

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: *"I was not able to do that logic."* Tip: Add @IshitaShah (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. BTW - not all people are suited to programming. When they throw their hands up in the air and reply *"I was not able to do that logic."* it's a sign you might be one of them.

Comment: @IshitaShah  I am new to java and selenium. I don’t know how to write the logic

Comment: using elemenent.sendKeys() you can send a string or direct a date. another way is using robot to simulate keypress event: Robot rob = new Robot();
  rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
  rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

Comment: @pburgr  it’s not working like that

Comment: Even if you are new , you must have tried something, show us what have you tried so far. We are not here to do your home work.